# Error on instance second fragment on viewPager

Tags: android, layout, android-viewpager, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

i'm doing a simple viewpager, my main is a FragmentActivity like this:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vtg_main);

    Log.w("bug bug", " ------------------------------------------------- inicia");

    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    Log.w("bug bug", " ------------------------------------------------- get act");

    fragmentos = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    fragmentos.add(new FragmentLineas());
    fragmentos.add(new FragmentMedicamentos());


    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new CustomPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
}
```

the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The Fragment:

```
package co.com.smartmedia.vademtg;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentLineas extends Fragment {

    private View myView;

    public FragmentLineas() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        myView = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.frame_lineas_layout);

        return myView;
    }

}
```

(the other fragment is the same code but with diferent object name)
and The layout for each fragment is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


</RelativeLayout>
```

The Error i'm getting:

```
07-01 08:09:40.168: E/FragmentManager(1888): No view found for id 0x7f060000 (co.com.smartmedia.vademtg:id/pager) for fragment FragmentMedicamentos{41c4cb78 #1 id=0x7f060000}
```

i don't know what to do, it's too simple, but when i create the second fragment object:

```
fragmentos.add(new FragmentLineas());
fragmentos.add(new FragmentMedicamentos());  //this onee
```

The error appears, and if i swap those lines, the error changes to the second  Class object.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change constructor of Fragments to:

```
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frame_medicamentos_layout, container, false);
```